# How to define multiple variables with lapply?

Tags: r, function, variables, lapply

I want to apply a function with multiple variables with different values to a list. I know how to do this with one changing variable

```
sapply(c(1:10), function(x) x * 2)
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

but not with two. I show you first manually what I want (actually I use  `lapply()` but `sapply()` is more synoptic in SO):

```
# manual
a <- sapply(c(1:10), function(x, y=2) x * y)
b <- sapply(c(1:10), function(x, y=3) x * y)
c <- sapply(c(1:10), function(x, y=4) x * y)
c(a, b, c)
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 
# [24]  16 20 24 28 32 36 40
```

And this is my attempt where I try to define both `x` and `y`.

```
# attempt
X <- list(x = 1:10, y = 2:4)
sapply(c(1:10, 2:4), function(x, y) x * y)
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

***Benchmark of solutions***

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sapply = as.vector(sapply(1:10, function(x, y) x * y, 2:4)), 
               mapply = mapply( FUN = function(x, y) x * y, 1:10, rep( x = 2:4, each = 10)),
               sapply2 = as.vector(sapply(1:10, function(y) sapply(2:4, function(x) x * y))),
               outer = c(outer(1:10, 2:4, function(x, y) x * y)))
# Unit: microseconds
# expr        min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
# sapply   34.212  36.3500  62.44864  39.1295  41.9090 2304.542   100
# mapply   62.008  65.8570  87.82891  70.3470  76.5480 1283.342   100
# sapply2 196.714 203.9835 262.09990 223.6550 232.2080 3344.129   100
# outer     7.698  10.4775  13.02223  12.4020  13.4715   53.883   100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### General solution

Try `outer`:

```
c(outer(1:10, 2:4, Vectorize(function(x, y) x*y)))
##  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20
## [26] 24 28 32 36 40
```

### If function is Vectorized already

If the function is already vectorized, as it is here, then we can omit `Vectorize`:

```
c(outer(1:10, 2:4, function(x, y) x * y))
##  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20
## [26] 24 28 32 36 40
```

### Particular example shown in question

In fact, in this particular case the anonymous function shown is the default so this would work:

```
c(outer(1:10, 2:4))
##  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20
## [26] 24 28 32 36 40
```

Also in this particular case we could use:

```
c(1:10 %o% 2:4)
##  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20
## [26] 24 28 32 36 40
```

### If input is list X

If your starting point is list `X` shown in the question then:

```
c(outer(X[[1]], X[[2]], Vectorize(function(x, y) x * y)))
##  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20
## [26] 24 28 32 36 40
```

or

```
c(do.call("outer", c(unname(X), Vectorize(function(x, y) x*y))))
##  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20
## [26] 24 28 32 36 40
```

where the prior sections apply to shorten it, if applicable.

Comment: The list approach I mentioned in imy comment under Joris' answer was dedicated to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Use mapply()

[`mapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html) applies a function to multiple list or vector arguments.

[`rep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html) was also used to repeat the values 2, 3, and 4. Specifying 10 in the `each` parameter, `rep()` repeats each element of `x` 10 times.

This is necessary since the first argument in `mapply()` - 1:10 - is of length 10.

```
# supply the function first, followed by the
# arguments in the order in which they are called in `FUN`
mapply( FUN = function(x, y) x * y
        , 1:10
        , rep( x = 2:4, each = 10)
)

# [1]   2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20
# [26] 24 28 32 36 40
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you can do this just with `lapply()` if you your function is vectorized. In this case, it is :

```
x <- 1:10
unlist(lapply(2:4, function(y) x*y))
# OR
unlist(lapply(2:4, function(x=x,y) x*y))
```

Second, if you need to apply a function on every combination of two vectors, use `outer()` :

```
xf <- 1:10
yf <- 2:4
c(xf %o% yf)
# OR spelled out for any function:
c(outer(xf,yf,FUN = `*`))
```

If you use mapply, you can use the argument `MoreArgs` to avoid having to use `rep` to construct your arguments :

```
xf <- 1:10
yf <- 2:4
mapply(function(x,y) x*y,
       y = yf,
       MoreArgs = list(x = xf))
```

That is the exact equivalent of the `lapply()` construct I've shown above. The resulting matrix can also be turned into a vector using `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` and `unlist()` :

```
unlist(mapply(function(x,y) x*y,
              y = yf,
              MoreArgs = list(x = xf),
              SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

Which solution is the most convenient, depend on your actual use case. Timing-wise they are all comparable, in recent R versions probably `outer()` will be a tad slower than the other solutions.

### Benchmarking

To show how results can vastly differ depending on the size and order of objects, I include the following benchmarking results (code and output below). This shows that :

1. `outer()` is not necessarily the fastest solution, although it often is one of the fastest.
2. manually repeating one vector in `mapply()` is adding so much overhead that even a double `sapply()` call is way faster.

The code: **Warning: this will run for a while**

```
fx <- sample(1e4)
fy <- sample(1e3)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sapply = as.vector(sapply(fx, function(x, y) x * y, fy)), 
               mapply = mapply( FUN = function(x, y) x * y, fx, rep( fy, each = 1e4)),
               sapply2 = as.vector(sapply(fx, function(y) sapply(fy, function(x) x * y))),
               outer = c(outer(fx, fy, function(x, y) x * y)),
               mapply2 = mapply(function(x,y) x*y, x=fx, MoreArgs = list(y = fy)),
               mapply3 = mapply(function(x,y) x*y, y=fy, MoreArgs = list(x = fx)),
               times = 15)
```

The output on my machine :

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr         min          lq       mean      median          uq        max neval cld
  sapply    89.52318    92.98653   344.1538   117.11280   239.64887  1485.3178    15 a  
  mapply 20471.02137 22925.42757 24478.5985 24650.29055 25627.31232 28840.3494    15   c
 sapply2  7472.02251  8268.04696  9519.8016  8707.19193  9528.46181 14182.7537    15  b 
   outer    77.62331    85.94651   189.5107    91.83722   182.08506  1119.6620    15 a  
 mapply2    77.76871    79.71924   143.9484    81.24168    84.53247   971.1792    15 a  
 mapply3    65.21709    71.85662   107.9586    73.80779   124.21141   242.0760    15 a
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, though the others are also great. `outer()` is much faster than other approaches, I provide a benchmark as an edit. Your implementation with my list approach is very nice.

Comment: @jaySf I did benchmarking as well, and on larger vectors outer becomes slower than the other two. Be careful how you benchmark, because the fastest solution in one case is not the fastest in another. I've learnt this the hard way..

Comment: @jaySf I've added the benchmarking with larger objects. There you can see that mapply applied correctly is marginally faster than outer. The part you forget in your benchmarking, is `MoreArgs`

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to use `sapply` twice.

```
as.vector(sapply(2:4, function(y) sapply(1:10, function(x) x * y)))
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
```

Or we can use `map2_int` from the `purrr` package. `map2_int` can loop through two vectors with the same length and make sure the output is integer. So we need to use `rep(a, length(b))` and `rep(b, each = length(a))` to make sure each element is paired. `~.x * .y` is a succinct way to specify function in `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)

a <- 1:10
b <- 2:4
map2_int(rep(a, length(b)), rep(b, each = length(a)), ~.x * .y)
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
```