# Apply an API Function over 2 columns of Dataframe, Output a Third Column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply, lapply

Here are the first four columns of a dataframe that is 20K long.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Address                            Address_Total    lon   lat
  <chr>                                      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 !500 s. dobson rd., mesa, AZ, 852…          14.1 -112.   33.4
2 # l10, jackson, MS, 39202, United…          16.1   NA    NA  
3 0 fletcher allen health care, bur…         300    -73.2  44.5
4 00 w main st # 110, babylon, NY, …         287.    NA    NA
```

I want to convert the geocodes in the dataframe (lon and lat values) to county codes (FIPS).  I found a great script that does that using FCC API. All you need is to input two lat / long values:

```
geo2fips <- function(latitude, longitude) {
  url <- "https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/block/find?format=json&latitude=%f&longitude=%f"
  url <- sprintf(url, latitude, longitude)
  json <- RCurl::getURL(url)
  json <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(json)
  as.character(json$County['FIPS'])
}
```

For instance, if I insert a combo of lat / long it comes up with this, which is perfect:

```
> # Orange County
> geo2fips(28.35975, -81.421988)
[1] "12095"
```

What I want to do is to use some member of the apply family to run geo2fips over the entire dataset from top to bottom. I would like the output to be a fifth column of my dataframe called "FIPS" or something like that, which just contains the FIPS codes.

Can anyone help? Been at this for hours and I can't get it to work. I'm sure there's just some syntax with using the apply family and I'm pretty sure that it's my fault because I'm not coercing the dataframe columns correctly.

Comment: You can use `mapply` like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598687/how-to-define-multiple-variables-with-lapply) and just assign the results to a new column in your data frame `df$FIPS <- mapply(geo2fips, df$lat, df$lon)`

Comment: You can use `Vectorize()` to create a function that accepts vectors and not just scalars.