# Convert Lat/Lon to County Codes using FCC API

Tags: r, json, function, api-design

I previously figured out how to convert lattitude/longitude to county FIPS codes using the FCC API ([Apply an API Function over 2 columns of Dataframe, Output a Third Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240111/apply-an-api-function-over-2-columns-of-dataframe-output-a-third-column)) thanks to @caldwellst and @rohit.  Unfortunately, the FCC modified the API and I can't figure out how to fix the code to work again.

Here is a link to the new API: https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/

Here is my dataframe:

```
> head(df_coords)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     lon   lat censusYear
   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 -112.   33.4       2010
2  -73.2  44.5       2010
3  -88.2  41.9       2010
4  -88.2  41.9       2010
5  -88.4  41.9       2010
6  -77.1  39.0       2010
```

Here is the function I previously borrowed / adapted as well as the command to run it:

```
geo2fips <- function(latitude, longitude) { 
  url <- "https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/block/find?format=json&latitude=%f&longitude=%f"
  url <- sprintf(url, latitude, longitude)
  json <- RCurl::getURL(url)
  json <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(json)
  as.character(json$County['FIPS'])
}

df_fips$county_fips <- mapply(geo2fips, df_fips$lat, df_fips$lon)
```

And here is the error message I get when I run it:

```
 Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to geo.fcc.gov:443
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? I figured it may be related to a requirement for census year, so I tried to modify the code as follows but it returned the same error message:

```
 geo2fips <- function(latitude, longitude, censusYear) { 
+   url <- "https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/block/find?format=json&latitude=%f&longitude=%f&censusYear=%f"
+   url <- sprintf(url, latitude, longitude, censusYear)
+   json <- RCurl::getURL(url)
+   json <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(json)
+   as.character(json$County['FIPS'])
+ }
> df_coords$county_fips <- mapply(geo2fips, df_coords$lat, df_coords$lon, df_coords$censusYear)
 Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to geo.fcc.gov:443 
>
```

Huge thank you to anyone who can help. -Mike

Answer (score 1):

There's been a slight change to the URL and parameters - you can use:

```
geo2fips <- function(latitude, longitude) { 
  url <- "https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/area?lat=%f&lon=%f&format=json"
  res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(sprintf(url, latitude, longitude))[["results"]][["county_fips"]]
  unique(res)
}
```

You can also simplify things a little if you use the `jsonlite` package instead of `RSJONIO` as the former accepts connections directly.

Comment: Brilliant! For some reason though the county_fips column in the resulting tibble is displaying a list, sometimes of duplicated characters.  Do you know why it would be doing that? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I fixed it by unnesting the list, using distinct() to remove the duplicates, then left joined the whole thing back into my dataframe.  So this isn't entirely essential but curious in case it's an issue. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Some of the queries return multiple records that seem, based on the limited sample co-ords, to differ on some fields.  If you're only after the FIPS field you can wrap the result within the function with `unique()` which should fix the issue (although I don't know enough about this data to say that there won't be instances of co-ordinates producing multiple distinct FIPS codes).